# setMethod for two different object signature in R

Tags: r, r-s4

How to make it using one setMethod as the function section is the same in the following two line codes? like signature("Triangle|Square"). Thank you.

```
setMethod("sides", signature("Triangle"), function(object) 3)
setMethod("sides", signature("Square"), function(object) 3)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usual approach is

```
.sides_body = function(object) 3
setMethod("sides", "Triangle", .sides_body)
setMethod("sides", "Square", .sides_body)
```

unless there is a class relationship and the definition is the same across classes

```
setClass("Shape")
setClass("Triangle", contains="Shape")
setClass("Square", contains="Shape")
setClass("Circle", contains="Shape")
setMethod("sides", "Shape", function(boject) 3)
setMethod("sides", "Circle", function(object) Inf)
```